# Issue with xcdatamodeld

Tags: iphone, core-data

i have `UserInfo.xcdatamodeld` and respective to entities UserInfo and Department. so if  i change or update my xcdatamodeld file i.e adding new attribute or update relationship in it, are those changes reflects in my NSManagedObject class files auto or i have to re create classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the NSManagedObject classes each time when you update the model file. When you'll do this, your classes will be updated with the latest available attributes & relationship. You can also add the attributes manually, but for avoiding the human errors better approach will be to delete old classes & add them dynamically.

Comment: ohk i'v done that ...but i was expecting xcode to update property in class as per attribute changed in model file.